# How to send dynamic push notification or stack of push notifications using cordova FCM plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am hybrid app developer and developing app using cordova plugins. I have used "https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm" plugin to implement push notification from my app. But currently i am seeing only last notification  which was sent recently. So i want to implement features like:

1. To show more than one push notifications arranged in stack manner(Please see attached sample[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azlUS.png)).
2. To customize push notification by adding some big image and button to provide click actions(Please see attached sample

[image]).

I researched a lot by googling but couldn't get any article where FCM is used to send multiple notifications & to customized the notification. I found some cordova plugin like "phonegap-plugin-push" but it is not helpful because they are using GCM(older version of FCM).

If anyone has implemented this type of features then please guide to fulfill it or else provide and any article or cordova plugin details so that i will implement it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: By *To show more than one push notifications arranged in stack manner.*, do you mean that notifications from your app are to just be separated instead of being bundled together?

Comment: @AL: I have updated my question number 1 and attached sample image of 1st requirement. The problem is that i am unable to send and stack more than one notifications one by one instead it is replacing older notification by newer one.

Answer (score 2):

[phonegap-plugin-push version 2.0.0-rc2](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/v2.0.x) uses **FCM** instead of **GCM**.

Take a look at [Push notification payload details](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/v2.0.x/docs/PAYLOAD.md) for the behaviors you need.

1. Use [Inbox Stacking](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/v2.0.x/docs/PAYLOAD.md#inbox-stacking) payload to show more than one push notifications arranged in stack manner.
2. Use [Picture Messages](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/v2.0.x/docs/PAYLOAD.md#picture-messages) payload to add big image and [Action Buttons](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/v2.0.x/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons-1) payload to provide click actions.

I haven't used version 2 yet (still on version 1.x), and i know i'm not solving you [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm) problems, but it might be a good workarround.